# Why do I get this error when I paste text into the Clion Run window?

Tags: c++, clion

I'm testing a simple program via Clion 2022.2.4.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
int main() {
    int n, num[10] = {0};
   std::cin >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        std::cin >> num[i];
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        std::cout << num[i] << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

When I paste the following into the Run window via the clipboard and hit Enter, it turns out as expected.

```
Input:
4
1 2 2 2
Output:
1 2 2 2
```

When I pasted the following into the Run window via the clipboard, hit the backspace key, typed 2, and then hit enter, the result changed.

```
Input:
4
1 2 2 2
Output:
1 2 2 24
```

We can see that the last number changes from 2 to 24. But in fact the input for both operations before and after is 4 1 2 2 2 2(At least that's what it looks like).

Meanwhile, I tried some other inputs

By typing 4 1 2 2 1 through the clipboard, then change the last 1 to 8, the output is as follows:

```
Input:
4
1 2 2 8
Output:
1 2 2 14
```

By typing 3 1 2 3 through the clipboard, then change the last 3 to 7, the output is as follows:

```
Input:
3
1 2 3
Output:
1 2 33
```

I noticed that it seems that the last anomalous number is a combination of the last number on the clipboard and n.

Also, if n is entered on the same line as another n numbers, the result is correct even if the last number is modified.

```
Input:
4 1 2 2 2
Output:
1 2 2 2
```

So I want to know what's going on here, or is this just a bug?

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)` allows `i` to range from 1 to `n`, ignoring 0 and shooting out of bounds if `n` is 10. Mind you nothing prevents `n` from being greater than 10, and that another, much more fun problem. In general when iterating a container, a `<=` in an loop exit condition is almost always wrong.

Comment: step through the program with CLion's debugger and watch exactly what happens. You'll be able to tell if its a mistake in your code or just some weird CLion behaviour, and if it turns out to be your code, you'll see what it did instead of what you wanted and either fix it or be able to improve the question.

Comment: Indices of any kind of arrays in c++ start from 0 (not 1) till n-1 (not n). Also in c++ is is better to use `std::vector` (or `std::array` for [small] fixed size arrays) than c style arrays.

Comment: Add `std::cout << std::endl;` before `return 0;`.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the issue you are having with the processing of terminal input.

Nevertheless there are several issues in your code:

1. Array indices are 0..n-1 (**not** 1..n) - where n is the number of elements.
2. In c++ is is better to use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of c style arrays
   (or [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for fixed size and usually small arrays).
   Using `std::vector` will make your code support an arbitrary array size (not bound by e.g. 10 like in your code).
3. As mentioned in the comments above, it is recomended to end the output with a newline to avoid having the terminal prompt on the same line.

Better version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int n;
    std::vector<int> num;
    std::cin >> n;
    num.resize(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        std::cin >> num[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        std::cout << num[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```